# literal class compile error with constexpr constructor and function (differ vc, g++)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    constexpr A() {}
    constexpr int area() {
        return 12;
    }
private:
//  constexpr int h = 3;
//  constexpr int w = 4;
};
int main()
{
    constexpr A a;
    constexpr int j = a.area();
    cout << j << endl;

}
```

Why the code above can't compile with MSVC compiler while works with g++? Isn't MSVC not as strict as other compilers? The difference results between MSVC and g++ is sometimes confusing. Which compiler should I rely on, any tips btw?

[image]
[image]

Comment: *"can't compile"* - tell us the full error message.

Comment: Which versions of the compilers? What version of C++?

Comment: @JohnZwinck  sorry, now I add a picture about the error.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: @TobySpeight o_o ....The text(code) of 2 images is exactly the same as the code I posted from the very beginning.

Comment: I thought you said there were error messages in them?  If so, they should be in the question (as text) instead of the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that a `constexpr` object implies `const`, which means you cannot call `area` as it is a non-const function. Mark `area` as `const` and that's it.

Alternatively, making `a` non-const will allow you to keep `area` non-const, which whilst odd, it's valid C++.

**EDIT**. Perhaps you are using C++14 or above. Your impression that a `constexpr` function implies `const` is a C++11 feature that was changed in later standards.

Comment: Sure, but making a non-const would make the constructor etc not be run at compile time. Kind of feels like the point of this.

Comment: but `constexpr` memeber function is implictly `const`.

Comment: @Rick No, it does not. `constexpr int area() const` notice the second `const`.

Comment: Yes, I am reading *C++ Primer* and it's C++11 I think. But I still don't understand why I can compiler this with g++ and I think my code is right.

Comment: @Rick When compiling with g++ use the command `-std=c++11` to compile in C++11 mode. https://godbolt.org/g/DZ5x2Q

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that I was using C11 for g++ but C14 for MSVC.