# What is the use of a constexpr on a non-const member function?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

The accepted answer in [literal class compile error with constexpr constructor and function (differ vc, g++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146622/literal-class-compile-error-with-constexpr-constructor-and-function-differ-vc#50146622) shows that in C++14 there is a difference in the way `constexpr int A::a()` and `constexpr A::a() const` can be used. i.e. `constexpr` on a member function does not imply that the function does not change the object it acts on.

The given example is:

```
struct A {
    constexpr A() {}
    constexpr int a() {return 12; }
    constexpr int b() const {return 12; }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr A a;
    // DOES NOT COMPILE as a() is not const
    // constexpr int j = a.a();
    const int k = a.b(); // Fine since b() is const
}
```

To me the `constexpr` on `a()` seems useless.
Is there a concrete use for `constexpr` on a non-`const` member function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Question: how do you create a constexpr array of size `1024` with all elements set to `0` except element element `42` which needs to be `11`?

```
#include <array>

constexpr auto make_my_array() -> std::array<int, 1024>
{
    std::array<int, 1024> a{};
    a[42] = 11; // std::array::operator[] is constexpr non-const method since C++17

    return a;
}

auto test()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 1024> a = make_my_array();
}
```

Or a better yet suggestion from @michael-anderson a `make_iota_array`:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto make_iota_array() -> std::array<int, N>
{
    std::array<int, N> a{};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        a[i] = i;

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Figures I'd cook up something crazy with templates when there's a perfectly clearer, and simpler example. +1.

Comment: @StoryTeller and I found a practical example

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you added a good value to this question especially regarding constant expression. Please don't delete it this time :)

Comment: I like this example. I guess you could even do a `make_iota_array<N>() -> array<int,N>` that initialized `a[k]=k` in a for loop - the kind of thing I've coded as awful template hackery before.

Answer (score 16):

`constexpr` means *"can be used where a constant expression is required"*. The *"implied const"* for declared objects doesn't mean we can't have non-const objects in other contexts. For instance, a somewhat contrived example, created from your own:

```
template<int>
struct foo {
};

struct A {
    int i = 0;
    constexpr A() {}
    constexpr int a() { return i; }
    constexpr int b() const {return 12; }
    constexpr A&  c() { ++i; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    foo<A{}.c().a()> f1;
}
```

Obviously the template argument must be a constant expression. Now, `A{}` is a prvalue of a literal type with a constexpr c'tor, and it's a non-const object. The member function is allowed to modify this "constant" because the entire computation can collapse to a constant expression at compile time. That's the rationale for the rules, on one foot.

Comment: Wow. I never even realized something like this would be possible. Guess I've gotta drag my mind out of the pre-2000 C++ mindset...